# Ajax request on PhoneGap faster on 2G then 3G

Tags: javascript, cordova

While developing a PhoneGap application for iOS and Android I found a strange behavior. Uploading a file to my server is faster via 2G then 3G.

This are the difference for a 265 kb file:

- `2G: 0m 32s`
- `3G: 7m 21s`

Of course I did run some speedtest (with [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) app) on my iPhone:

- `2G: down: ~4 kB/s; up: ~2 kB/s`
- `3G: down: ~280 kB/s; up: ~110 kB/s`

This is my code in PhoneGap app:

```js
// base64 encoded image of 265kb
var base64img = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQA...";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://my.server.nl',
    data: {img: encodeURIComponent(base64img)},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
}).done(function(result){
    console.log('done: ' + result);
}).fail(function(result){
    console.log('fail: ' + result);
});
```

Which genius can tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Its really helpful which is ur 2G card?

Comment: What do you mean? I use a (dutch) Vodafone card in The Netherlands.

Comment: I just read somewhere if you are on 3g they have a max dl/ul of 1mb/min? i dont know how to solve it but i saw that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988375/max-payload-size-for-http-request-and-response-iphone/1988388#1988388

Comment: @four I only test with a 265kb file, which is less then 1mb. It's also a limit for both edge and 3G. So that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally solved the problem for uploading stuff via 'slow' 3G.

The problem really was different. We used *Vodafone* as mobile operator, but we tried another operator (**bliep*) and it was working well. So *Vodafone* was the problem. We found out that *Vodafone* was modifying the headers. It changed `Connection: close` to `Connection: Keep-Alive`.

Now we using an SSL (HTTPS) connection, so *Vodafone* can't change any headers. We haven't had any problems after changing to SSL.